# Why won't this Windows update install?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-update

Windows 7 Professional 64-bit Windows Update says that update KB4516048 can be installed on my device:

[image]

The update is not rejected and I am allowed to apply the update:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But after some time of it fails:

[image]

I deleted my SoftwareDistribution folder, ran Disk Cleanup, and `sfc /scannow`. I also cleared WindowsUpdate.log before running this update.

Here is a copy of WindowsUpdate.log:

https://pastebin.com/raw/7GhQDqzi

I haven't been able to figure out how to get this update installed. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/september-24-2019-kb4516048-preview-of-monthly-rollup-9a6dd3cb-56d7-ae2f-d3b7-5adf866ed293

Comment: This is the correct answer. I was missing KB4490628 specifically. I don't know why it wasn't offered by Windows Update.